# Blackberry PopupScreen size limited by virtual keyboard

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I am trying to display a Custom PopupScreen and when the virtual keyboard is being displayed it reduces the size of the popup. I know when you for example, select new message you get a PopupScreen that allows you to select message type (sms, email, etc) and it shows on top of the virtual keyboard. Here is my code am I missing something? I can't find a z-index or something similar...

```
public class InsertApplicationMenuItem extends ApplicationMenuItem {
    public Object run(Object context) {
    InsertWhatScreen screen = new InsertWhatScreen();

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushModalScreen(screen);

    return context;
    }
}

public class InsertWhatScreen extends PopupScreen {
    public InsertWhatScreen() {
    super(new VerticalFieldManager(), FOCUSABLE);
    }
}
```

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2645315/2010-01-20%2015%2017%2023.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2645315/2010-01-20%2015%2017%2023.png)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to put anything on top of the virtual keyboard from a third-party app.  If you read the display height while the virtual keyboard is showing, you'll see that the device actually shrinks the "screen size" given to your app while the keyboard is showing.

Comment: Your users won't thank you for that... if they virtual keyboard is up, they likely have it up for a reason.